# error C2664: multimap in map

Tags: c++, c2664

Here is my code:

```
map<string, multimap<string, string>> mp;
string str1 = "abc";
string str2 = "def";
string str3 = "ghi";
mp.insert(str1, {str2, str3});
```

I got an error C2664:

```
'void std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>' c:\users\thomas\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\test\test\main.cpp    14  1   test
```

It seems that I should use `make_pair` so I try like this:

```
mp.insert(std::make_pair(str1, std::make_pair(str2, str3)));
```

But I still get the same error.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map::insert` is expecting `string` and `multimap<string, string>` as its parameter.
Here`mp.insert(str1, {str2, str3});`
You are passing `string` and an `initializer_list<string>` as parameters.

If you want to `insert` then,

```
mp.insert(make_pair(str1, multimap<string, string>{{make_pair(str2, str3)}}));
```

Comment: your reply helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: `mp.insert({str1, multimap<string, string>{{str2, str3}}});` This works. Can you tell me why it is `multimap<string, string>{{str2, str3}}`, instead of `multimap<string, string>{str2, str3}`?

Comment: ahh, I got it. Now I'm clear about `{}` in c++11. :D

Comment: `{{make_pair(str2, str3)}}` means call constructor with `initializer_list` `{make_pair(str2, str3)}` will create `initializer_list`. `<>{make_pair(str2, str3)}` will also work but `<>(make_pair(str2, str3))` wont work.  `<>({make_pair(str2, str3)})` will work.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying initialize the multimap with std::pair. I think you meant something like this:

```
multimap<string, string> mm;
mm.insert(std::make_pair(str2, str3));
mp.insert(std::make_pair(str1, mm));
```

or

```
multimap<string, string> mm({{str2, str3}});
mp.insert(std::make_pair(str1, mm));
```

Comment: Dang it, you beat me to it. :) @Thomas Here is also a nice example how to work with maps: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/ From what I see you actually have difficulties understanding how the insert works.

Comment: in fact, I knew that this would work: `multimap<string, string> mm({{str2, str3}});
mp.insert({str1, mm});` So I thought that `mp.insert({str1, {str2, str3}});` should work too. I think I don't get the `{}` in c++11 correctly.